# How to select only certain JSON Keys

Tags: javascript, json

From a Web Socket call , i will recive different JSON Formats as response as showin below

The One Starting with "AS"
The another one starting with "SD"

**First JSON**

```
[
    [
        "AS",
        "POWER",
        "SMLL"
    ],
    [
        "AS",
        "SART",
        "SDF"
    ]

]
```

---

**Second JSON**

```
[
    [
        "SD",
        "R",
        "DSL"
    ],
    [
        "SD",
        "R",
        "DSL"
    ]

]
```

---

I am trying to debug and  want to see what  i get as Response , so i want to print only the key that has "AS" (The First JSON shown above)

This is my WebSocket HTML program

```
function testWebSocket() 
{
websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri); 
websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };
}




function onMessage(evt)
{

evt.data[1]

    writeToScreen('<span style="color: blue;">' + evt.data+'</span>');

}
```

Please let me know how to put a condition so that it only prints the "AS" Keys only .

Answer (score 0):

Run this on the data returned from the socket:

```
//somehow assign the result of the socket to theData
goodData=new Array();
parsed=JSON.parse(theData);
for(i=0;i<parsed.length;i++){
    if(parsed[i][0]=='AS')
        goodata.push(parsed[i])
}
stringifiedData=JSON.stringify(goodData);
//now, stringifiedData is a string containing only the values starting with "AS"
```

This is not tested, so tell me if it doesn't work in a comment.